# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'X', table 'DB139.dbo.Y'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm working on a SQL Server.

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Payment(
    Cust_ID                 CHAR(4),
    Credit_Card_Number      CHAR(16),
    Payment_Number          INTEGER,
    Date                    DATE,
    Fee                     MONEY,
    PRIMARY KEY (Cust_ID, Credit_card_number, Payment_number))

ALTER TABLE Payment
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CustPays
        FOREIGN KEY (Cust_ID) 
        REFERENCES Customer(Cust_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
; 

ALTER TABLE Payment
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CardPayment
        FOREIGN KEY (Credit_Card_Number) 
        REFERENCES Credit_card(Credit_card_number) ON DELETE CASCADE
;
```

As you can probably tell, this is a weak entity. I suspect this is the reason why I can't insert values into it with the INSERT INTO statement, like this:

```
Insert into Payment(Payment_number,Date,Fee) Values ('918702','2016-08-12',93);
```

I get the error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Cust_ID', table 'DB139.dbo.Payment'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I have successfully inserted data into all of my other tables this way. The only 2 tables that have also been affected by this are the other 2 weak entities (the tables Savings_account and Checking_account). As you can tell, I haven't included any NULL values, so I'm not sure what this error is about.

Here are the 2 other weak entities, for reference (after the "Account" table):

```
CREATE TABLE  Account(  
   Account_number           CHAR(10),
   Balance                  MONEY,
   Name_of_bank             VARCHAR(50),
   Date_of_creation         DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY  (Account_number))

ALTER TABLE Account
    ADD Account_number CHAR(16)
    CONSTRAINT FK_AccountNumberDouble
        FOREIGN KEY (Credit_card_number) 
        REFERENCES Credit_card(Credit_card_number) ON DELETE CASCADE
;

ALTER TABLE Account
    ADD Cust_ID CHAR(4)
    CONSTRAINT FK_CustIDTriple
        FOREIGN KEY (Cust_ID) 
        REFERENCES Customer(Cust_ID) 
;    

CREATE TABLE Savings_account(
  Account_number      CHAR(10),
  Interest_rate       INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY  (Account_number))

ALTER TABLE Savings_account
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SavingsAccount
        FOREIGN KEY (Account_number) 
        REFERENCES Account(Account_number) 
;    

CREATE TABLE Checking_account(
  Account_number        CHAR(10),
  Overdraft_limit       MONEY,
  PRIMARY KEY  (Account_number))

ALTER TABLE Checking_account
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CheckingAccount
        FOREIGN KEY (Account_number) 
        REFERENCES Account(Account_number) 
;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error is straightforward. A primary key cannot have null values. If you insert a record into Payments, it must have a cust_id, credit_card_number, and payment_number - these fields are the primary key of the table.

Comment: I think you will be much better off having a int identity id for your tables. Having composite ids such as you have done causes pain for little benefit. Having a non-meaningful ID is regular best practice.

Comment: I would strongly re-think having a composite primary key over multiple fixed-length char columns, this is not going to be performant, will likely lead to page-splits and fragmentation and will add 24 bytes to every row in any non-clustered index.

Answer (score -1):

you should be insert value for **Cust_ID** because it not identity and it primary key..

or you **alter Cust_ID to identity**